# How do I prevent Perforce from converting relative symbolic links to absolute symbolic links?

Tags: perforce, symlink

When adding files from a directory on a computer that contains relative symbolic links, for example:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 1001 1001     13 Nov 26  2013 recurse.mk -> mk/recurse.mk
```

it converts them to absolute path names on a computer that gets the latest version.  To top that off, the abosulte link is based on the file location on the computer used to populate the stream.

For example, if the above link was in the directory:

```
/home/foo/theDirectory
```

On the destination computer the link would look like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 1001 1001     13 Nov 26  2013 recurse.mk -> /home/foo/theDirectory.
```

How can I get perforce to stop translating symbolic links?

Comment: Pretty sure it's not supposed to do that.  Have you opened a bug with `support@perforce.com`?

Comment: I have sent in a support request, looking for clarification.  Thanks @Sam Stafford